# Portfolio margin account overnight leverage

Tags: united-states, stocks, margin, regulation

I know for a regular margin account, the requirements of Regulation T generally limit leverage on equity to 2:1, which means SMA has to be positive for overnight.

How about a portfolio margin account? Could leverage goes above 2:1 overnight for a portfolio margin account? I think this means SMA can be negative for a portfolio margin account, right?

Answer (score 1):

> I know for a regular margin account, the requirements of Regulation T generally limit leverage on equity to 2:1, which means SMA has to be positive for overnight.

Both statements are true but they are not linked as your statement implies.

The initial margin requirement is 50%.

SMA is the buying power or excess equity available in a margin account for buying additional securities (cash plus available margin).

If one goes to full margin, SMA is zero.  However, a decline in the value of the holdings does not cause SMA to decline below zero. It causes a lower margin amount which results in a restricted account (margin between 25% and 50%).  At that point, additional purchases must be funded by the additional initial margin requirement.

Comment: But how does a portfolio margin account work differently?

Comment: Explaining portfolio margin is beyond the scope of an answer here.  Google "Portfolio Margin" and you'll see how it is handled.